# Why I only skip 10 with heavenly strike now after the recent 7/17 update?

Tags: tap-titans-2

> Heavenly Strike upgrades now increase splash skip instead of splash
>   count.
>
> Angelic Radiance now increases splash count instead of splash skip.
>
> Heavenly Strike base splash count increase.

https://www.reddit.com/r/TapTitans2/comments/cch54d/tt2_devlog_45_preview_of_v32/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app

I used to do 30 per heavenly strike. Now I only do 20 near my maximum stage.

I wonder why?

[image]

I noticed that my splash skip is now very high 127, higher than number of titans of my MS but my splash count is very low, only 19. So I have to upgrade Angelic Radiance?

Why is my splash skip is very high?

Also what does it mean by upgrading Heavenly Strike? Does it mean spending gold to max out Heavenly Strike? It doesn't increase number of staged skipped

Comment: To be honest, the patch notes tell you why. Unless your splash count and splash skip were the same, it's a fair assumption that swapping the two values would change the end result. Luckily, you can earn your way back to where you were. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can see your HS splash count is 19. If you have enough splash skip from HS skill. It means that in the best case scenario, you'll face 1 titans and 1 boss (or 1 boss if snap is active). So it's 19/2= 8 stages skipped (or 19 with snap active).
In order to skip more stages, you have to invest more SP in AR.

For this patch they swapped. Now AR increases splash count and the HS skill increases splash skip, before it was the opposite.

Splash skip is the number of titans you'll skip per stage. In order to splash efficiently, you need your splash skip to be higher than your max number of titan.
Splash count is the number of titans you'll kill after splash skip has been taken into acocunt.

Example : titans/stage = 100, splash skip = 96, splash count = 20
it will be like you were facing 4 titans per stage (100-91), so a total of 5 (because +1 for the boss). Since you can kill a total of 20 titans (your splash count), you'll skip 5 stages (20/5).

Something to know, without snap active, the best you can face is 1 titan + 1 boss. When snap is active, it's 0 titan + 1 boss.